# Outline 2D mesh equal distance to edges

Tags: mesh, bevel

Not sure how to call this, there's similar named questions in blender but those are far from what I am trying to do.

### What I want & what I have

- An edge loop that has equal distance to target object's edges (Black part in below image)
  [image]
- Could manage to make sharper one via *Mesh Tools > Offset Edges*
  [image]

---

### Answers I've tried

- Skin modifier - absolutely broke
  [image]
- Bevel edge - can't set equal radius if angle is not 90
  [image]
- Bevel edge modifier - setting Limit method to Weight does absolutely nothing
  [image]

---

Is there way to make this work?

Even if it only works in 3D mesh (aka shell around entire object) that would be totally fine with me!

Currently I'm just performing bevel manually in 2-step as a workaround.
[image]

---

### Edit

Below answer worked great! Managed to 3D print badge that doesn't hurt user!

[image]

---

Comment: Are you looking to inset individual faces?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Probably not, that sounds like something I would try with individual origins - but I'm trying to make *Black part* on the top image in blender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable the shipped add-on [***Add Curve: Curve Tools***](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/add_curve/curve_tools.html#curve-edit), an operator: *Recursive Offset* becomes available.

If *Recursive Offset* is invoked in Edit Mode on a 2D curve, then you can generate a filled stroke, with an option of rounding at junctions.

This shows the effect on  a copy of your 2D shape (in red), given its own black material:

[image]

.. actually that's 2 overlapping copies, one each for inner and outer strokes, The outer has rounded junctions. As you can see, the documentation is hardly extensive, a minute or two's play can make up for it.

The curves can be converted to mesh, messed about with (probably including a *Limited Dissolve* to get rid of excess triangilation), and extruded, if that's what you're after:

[image]

Comment: Absolutely what I was looking for. Thanks! FYI I was creating a 2-Colored Badge for 3D printing, printed out sample and thought it was way too sharp and dangerous for daily use - round corners was a must.

Comment: Feels like there's always a disabled shipped addon for every problem newbies encounter - like `Mesh Tools` and `TinyCAD`. I'm reading the addon list on [Blender Official documents](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_curve/index.html) but those are mostly without any example - making it hard to learn intuition in which situation I should be using those. Mind to share how you encountered/learned to use the `Curve Tools`?

Comment: @jupiterbjy I could say: 'by answering your post', and that would almost be true :) I've had shots at using bits of _Curve Tools_ in the past, for myself, and well, it's a bit untidy. While nice in parts, not surprised they're not yet part of Blender proper. I wish a Grease Pencil stroke could be converted to curve, including its stroke... AHA!

Comment: @jupiterbjy . just found another way. 1 Convert Curve > Grease Pencil, 2 Adjust stroke as desired. Export GP as SVG. 3 Import SVG as curve. Why you can't do that directly.. mystery. Thanks for the prompt :)

Comment: Ah, sadly tried about 20 mins but couldn't recreate second method (Blender 3.4.1) - So far exported `.svg` do have outlines but normal `import stl` simply gives me lines without thickness, couldn't find `import svg as curve` in addon-list either - updating blender rn

Comment: @jupiterbjy it works with a default monkey.. so we've just got to figure out how those strokes are characterized (and they _are_ strokes) .. I've got a lot to learn about 2D.. may post a q of my own, when I've played enough to make it sensible.